Angular Reactive Forms: Validate that Nested FormArray is Not Empty and Show mat-error
I am working with Angular's reactive forms and have a nested structure where I need to validate that a FormArray of files within another FormArray is not empty. Specifically, each groupFiles can have multiple groups, and each group contains a FormArray of files. I need to display a mat-error message if any group's files array is empty.
My Form Structure
Here's how I've set up my form:
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class MyComponent {
  serviceRequestForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.serviceRequestForm = this.fb.group({
      groupFiles: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  get groupFiles(): FormArray {
    return this.serviceRequestForm.get('groupFiles') as FormArray;
  }

  addGroupFile(groupFile: any) {
    const fileControls = this.fb.array([
      this.fb.group({
        fileName: ['', Validators.required],
        is_high: [false, Validators.required],
        uploadFileName: '',
        fileType: '',
        fileBase64: '',
      })
    ]);

    const group = this.fb.group({
      groupFileId: [groupFile.ID],
      groupName: [groupFile.DISPLAY_DESCRIPTION, Validators.required],
      orderNo: [groupFile.ORDER_NO, Validators.required],
      files: fileControls
    });

    this.groupFiles.push(group);
  }

  removeGroupFile(index: number) {
    this.groupFiles.removeAt(index);
  }
}

The Template
I am trying to show an error if the files array is empty using mat-error:
<div formArrayName="groupFiles">
  <div *ngFor="let groupFile of groupFiles.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <span class="col-sm-12">{{ i + 1 }}</span>
    <mat-form-field style="width: 80%" appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Group Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" formControlName="groupName" id="groupName" />
      <mat-error *ngIf="groupFile.get('groupName')?.hasError('required')">
        Field is required
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="groupFile.get('files')?.value?.length === 0">
        Files are required for this group.
      </mat-error>
      <button mat-icon-button color="warn" type="button" matSuffix (click)="removeGroupFile(i)">
        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>

The Issue
The mat-error for checking if the files array is empty is not working as expected. The length check on files does not seem to trigger the error display correctly. I have tried a few things, but none seem to work:

I tried adding a custom validator to check if the files array is empty.

I tried using .length === 0 directly in the template.


What I've Tried

Custom Validator:

import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function filesNotEmptyValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (formArray: AbstractControl) => {
    const files = formArray.value;
    return files && files.length > 0 ? null : { filesNotEmpty: true };
  };
}

Applied like this:
const group = this.fb.group({
  groupFileId: [groupFile.ID],
  groupName: [groupFile.DISPLAY_DESCRIPTION, Validators.required],
  orderNo: [groupFile.ORDER_NO, Validators.required],
  files: this.fb.array(fileControls, filesNotEmptyValidator())
});

Template Length Check:
<mat-error *ngIf="groupFile.get('files')?.value?.length === 0">
  Files are required for this group.
</mat-error>

What I Need
I want to validate that the files FormArray is not empty and show an error message using mat-error if it is. How can I correctly implement this validation and ensure the error is displayed?

You are not getting errors, because you are always having default value in const fileControls = this.fb.array([       this.fb.group({         fileName: ['', Validators.required],         is_high: [false, Validators.required],         uploadFileName: '',         fileType: '',         fileBase64: '',       })     ]); and files: fileControls

that didn't worked too, i removed that default value, and tried, still no display of the error, sorry that i did not mentioned in the question

Like Naren said in the comments, you're not seeing any mat-error since the array is never length 0.
Maybe you want to access the properties inside the array instead like this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-22jqif?file=src%2Fmain.ts

You are not validating the actual control, but showing errors of another control in this control, for this you can use errorStateMatcher to show the errors. Feel free to tune this function to suit your requirements.
TS:
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(
    control: FormControl | null,
    form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null
  ): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    const filesControlErrors =
      (control?.parent?.controls as any)?.['files'].errors || {};
    return !!(
      control &&
      (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted) &&
      (control.errors?.['required'] || filesControlErrors?.['filesNotEmpty'])
    );
  }
}

...


...
matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();

HTML:
<input matInput type="text" formControlName="groupName" id="groupName" 
[errorStateMatcher]="matcher" />
      <mat-error *ngIf="groupFile.get('groupName')?.hasError('required')">
        Field is required
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="!groupFile.get('groupName')?.hasError('required') && groupFile.get('files')?.value?.length === 0">
        Files are required for this group.
      </mat-error>

Full Code:
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormArray,
  Validators,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormControl,
  FormGroupDirective,
  NgForm,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';

export function filesNotEmptyValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (formArray: AbstractControl) => {
    const files = formArray.value;
    return files && files.length > 0 ? null : { filesNotEmpty: true };
  };
}

/** Error when invalid control is dirty, touched, or submitted. */
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(
    control: FormControl | null,
    form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null
  ): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    const filesControlErrors =
      (control?.parent?.controls as any)?.['files'].errors || {};
    return !!(
      control &&
      (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted) &&
      (control.errors?.['required'] || filesControlErrors?.['filesNotEmpty'])
    );
  }
}

/** @title Simple form field */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-overview-example',
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="serviceRequestForm">
    <div formArrayName="groupFiles">
      <div *ngFor="let groupFile of groupFiles.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <span class="col-sm-12">{{ i + 1 }}</span>
        <mat-form-field style="width: 80%" appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Group Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="text" formControlName="groupName" id="groupName" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" />
          <mat-error *ngIf="groupFile.get('groupName')?.hasError('required')">
            Field is required
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="!groupFile.get('groupName')?.hasError('required') && groupFile.get('files')?.value?.length === 0">
            Files are required for this group.
          </mat-error>
          <button mat-icon-button color="warn" type="button" matSuffix (click)="removeGroupFile(i)">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class FormFieldOverviewExample {
  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
  serviceRequestForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.serviceRequestForm = this.fb.group({
      groupFiles: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addGroupFile({
      ID: 1,
      DISPLAY_DESCRIPTION: 'one',
      ORDER_NO: 1001,
    });
  }

  get groupFiles(): FormArray {
    return this.serviceRequestForm.get('groupFiles') as FormArray;
  }

  addGroupFile(groupFile: any) {
    const fileControls = this.fb.array([
      this.fb.group({
        fileName: ['', Validators.required],
        is_high: [false, Validators.required],
        uploadFileName: '',
        fileType: '',
        fileBase64: '',
      }),
    ]);

    const group = this.fb.group({
      groupFileId: [groupFile.ID],
      groupName: [groupFile.DISPLAY_DESCRIPTION, Validators.required],
      orderNo: [groupFile.ORDER_NO, Validators.required],
      files: this.fb.array([], filesNotEmptyValidator()),
    });

    this.groupFiles.push(group);
  }

  removeGroupFile(index: number) {
    this.groupFiles.removeAt(index);
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

NOTE: From Angular 11, Validators.required give you error {required:true} when a formArray is empty (it's not neccesary create any custom validator)

<mat-error *ngIf="groupFiles.length === 0">
Files are required for this group.


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
